# Why are shared and static libraries different things?

Tags: c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking

For an application developer the difference between shared (.so) and static (.a) libraries is entirely a difference in how you use them - roughly speaking whether the library code you need is copied into your program, or just referenced from your program then loaded at run time.

Conceptually (and naively) it seems there could just be one kind of library.  Static versus dynamic linking would be an option you select when building your own application.  **What are the technical differences between .so and .a that require this choice to be made when building the *library*, not when building your *application*?**

An analogy:  At a restaurant, you may order food to stay or to go, but this is *your* choice of how to "use" the food; the chef cooks you the same hamburger.

Comment: I think it is just a historical thing, first everything was static linked then somebody thought it was a good idea to share code to save space both in memory and on disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I see lots of answers talking about why you would want to use shared libraries instead of static libraries, but I think your question is why they are even distinct things nowadays, i.e. why isn't it possible to use a shared library as a static library and pull what you need out of it at build time?

Here are some reasons. Some of these are historical - keep in mind that something as fundamental as binary formats changes very slowly in computer systems.

### Compiled Differently

Code can be compiled either to be dependent on the address it sits at (position-dependent) or independent (position-independent). This affects things like loads of global constants, function calls, etc. Position-dependent code needs fixups if it isn't loaded at the address it expects, i.e. the loader has to go over the code and actually change offsets.

For executables, this isn't a problem. An executable is the first thing that is loaded into the address space, so it will always be loaded at the same address. You generally don't need any fixups. But a shared library is used by different executables, by different processes. Multiple libraries can conflict: if they expect to be at overlapping address ranges, one will have to budge. When it does, and it is position-dependent, it needs to be fixed by the loader. But now you have process-specific changes in the library code, which means the code can't be shared (at runtime) with other processes anymore. You lose one of the big benefits of shared libraries.

If the shared library uses position-independent code (PIC), it doesn't need fixups. So PIC is good for shared libraries. On the other hand, PIC is slower on some architectures (notably x86, but not x64), so compiling executables as PIC is a waste of resources.

Executables were therefore usually compiled as position-dependent code, while shared libraries were compiled as position-independent code. If you used shared libraries as sources for code directly pulled into executables, you get PIC. If you want PDC, you need a separate code repository, and that's a static library.

Of course, on most modern architectures, PIC isn't less efficient than PDC, and security techniques like address space randomization make it useful to compile executables as PIC too, so this is more of a historical reason than a current one.

### Contain Different Things

But there's another, more current reason for separating static and shared libraries, and that's link-time optimization.

Basically, the more information an optimizer has about a program, the better it can reason about it. Classical optimizer worked on a per-module basis: compile a .c file, optimize it, generate object code. The linker took all the object files and merged them together. This means that the optimizer can only reason about one module at a time. It cannot look into the called functions that are outside the module in order to reason about them, or even simply inline them.

In modern toolchains, however, the compiler often works differently. Instead of compiling and optimizing a module and then producing object code, it takes a module, produces an intermediate form, possibly optimizes it a bit, and then puts the intermediate form into the object file. The linker, instead of just merging object files and resolving references, actually merges the intermediate representation and then invokes the optimizer and code generator on the merged form. With much more information available, the optimizer can do a vastly better job.

This intermediate representation is more detailed, more faithful to the original code than machine code. You want this for your compilation process. You don't want to ship it to the customer, because it is much bigger, and if you use a closed-source model also because it is much easier to reverse-engineer. Moreover, there's no point in shipping it, because the loader doesn't understand it, and you don't want to re-optimize and recompile your program at startup time anyway (JIT languages aside).

Thus, a shared library contains real object code. A static library, on the other hand, is a good container for intermediate code, because it is consumed by the linker. This is a key difference between static and shared libraries.

### Linkage Model

Finally, we have another semi-historical reason: linkage.

Linkage defines how a symbol (a variable or function name) is visible outside a code unit. The C language defines two linkages: internal (not visible outside the compilation unit, i.e. `static`) and external (visible to the whole program, i.e. `extern`). You generally have a lot of externally visible symbols.

Shared libraries, however, have their symbols resolved at load time, and this should be fast. Fewer symbols means lookup in the symbol table is faster. Of course this was more relevant when computers were slower, but it still can have a noticeable effect. It also affects the *size* of the libraries.

Therefore, object file specifications used by the operating systems (ELF for *nix, PE/COFF for Windows) defined separate visibilities for shared libraries. Instead of making everything that's external in C visible, you have the option to specify the visible functions explicitly. (In Windows, only things annotated as `__declspec(dllexport)`, or listed in a .def file are exported from a DLL. In Linux, everything extern is exported by default, but you can use `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` to not do that, or you can specify the `-fvisibility=hidden` command line switch or the visibility pragma to override the default.)

The end result is that a shared library throws away all symbol information except for the exported functions.

A static library has no need to throw away any symbol information. What's more, you don't want to do that, because carefully specifying which functions are exported and which aren't is some work, and you don't want to have to do that work unless necessary. If you're using static libraries, it isn't necessary.

So a shippable shared library should minimize its exported symbols in order to be fast and small. This makes it less useful as a code repository for static linking, where you may want a greater selection of functions to link in, especially once the interface functions get inlined (see link-time optimization above).

Comment: About fixups. _Both_ static and shared libraries need fixups. For _some_ platforms the linker can resolve fixups while linking the application (and sometimes fixups are resolved only at load-time even for the application object itself - recall good ol' DOS executables).

Comment: I haven't been programming that long. I wrote my first C++ program in Windows 95.

Comment: Well, still there are many (embedded) platforms wthout virtual memory at all, so they need some trick to make code position-independent. Yet quite often they lack a sophisticated kernel/loader, which means the application must handle relocations itself.

Comment: Do such platforms even have shared libraries?

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding my question, and for providing this excellent, clear answer.   Amazing!

Answer (score 3):

It is operating system specific.

On Linux, shared libraries have some features that static libraries don't have

- a shared library is an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object file.
- some of the [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) of a shared library happens at runtime (in `ld-linux.so`)
- updating a shared library to a newer release (for bug fixes) with the *same* [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is very simple and transparent to applications (after upgrading the shared library, just restart the applications using it).
- shared libraries are shared by *several* processes (they use the same file on disk, and most of the memory, in particular their [code segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment), is shared)
- you can link one shared library into another one (but you cannot really link a static library into another static library; you could copy its members into another static library).
- you can use the `visibility` attribute to limit visibility of defined names to that shared libraries
- you can [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) a shared library (as a plugin) with `dlopen`
- you should **build a shared library as [position-independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)** 
  <sup>(In theory you don't have to make PIC shared libraries. But in practice, you should, for performance & technical reasons).</sup>
   *This* PIC thing *is why you need to build shared libraries differently than static libraries*.
- ELF symbol versioning matters for shared libraries.

Static libraries are becoming nearly useless (at least in principle). In practice they are mostly needed to build the few executables (e.g. `/bin/sash`) that you don't want to depend on external resources (e.g. `libc.so` or `ld-linux.so`) or when you want to avoid a [dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

The developer should also be careful that the same shared library is not loaded -i.e. `mmap`-ed - twice (but `dlopen` or `ld-linux.so` usually cares well enough about that). When that happens the data segment might get duplicated and chaos happens.

A better way to ask your question could have been "when should I avoid shared libraries"? And the answer is almost "never" (with a few exceptions).

Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO), [C++ dlopen mini HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/), [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

BTW, it is mostly a historical artifact. In the old days -1990 to 1995?- of Linux 1 (or Linux 0.99) kernel, ELF was not yet supported by the kernel, and `a.out` shared libraries where very painful (at that time, no PIC, and you had to decide *globally* about the used address segments). Also, at that time processors where hundreds of time slower than today, so the runtime linking startup time could have make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference IMO is the fact that dynamic libraries can be loaded by an already built app. This means that if there is a bug in dll then the bug can be fixed by rebuilding only the lib(as long as You don't mess with the symbols).
Also the run time linking allows dll's to be plugins extending applications functionality. The app would search for them in a directory and load all of them as long as their interface is the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's not analogous to food at all since *shared* libraries are, um, *shared*.  You'd hardly order a hamburger that any given number of people will also be eating at the same time as you.  That's why you need different implimentations of libraries, they have to either reside in memory where other can access them, or loaded for your exclusive use.

Comment: if you had a single library for both static and shared linking, all of the binaries which linked it as shared would get one copy of it in memory but the code that links it statically would have the library copied into them, so it's not a contradiction at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. Static library is a collection of object modules. **Any subset of modules** may be linked into the resulting application (if all dependencies are resolved). Unlike the static, the shared library is loaded into application's space as **one entity**.
2. Shared libraries are loaded by OS, so they must have a special format recognized by **system utilities/kernel**. Static libraries are processed by linker/librarian application(s). Although there are some specifications, it's possible to develop **own format** static libraries (and tools capable to process it).

Answer (score -1):

When building a library (or more accurately, when installing it, or perhaps when building a binary package), a choice is made to build static libraries, shared libraries, or both.  If dependencies exist in only one form, then the choice is to either build (and install) only that form, or to rebuild/reinstall the dependencies of the desired format.  The same choice is faced by the builder/installer of the application.  The only technical difference between the libraries that influences the choice of which to install is the status of installed dependencies.  Or, to say it another way, there is no technical difference which influences the decision of which to build.  (Except questions of disk space, runtime latency, etc., but these decisions are deferred until the application is built.)

In other words, the choice *is* made when you build the application.

Comment: this does not anwser his question: his question: why are they different when being built; while you could imagine them being the same binary file but being used either dynamically or builtin

Comment: @ChrisMaes It renders the question moot.  The question is what differences make a choice necessary when the library is built, and it answers it by pointing out that there is no such necessity.  So the short answer is: "None".  There are technical differences between the two types of libraries, but none of them force a decision at build time.  Except perhaps the lack of existence of dependencies.  If a library depends on libraries for which static versions are not available, the library builder has to choose to either build only a dynamic version, or to also build all static dependencies.

Comment: please edit your answer accordingly, then I can remove my downvote. You comment makes your answer maybe a little more digestable